# Check last stable AppStore version of my app from code

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

In my code, I check for the version of my app that is available on the AppStore so I can prompt the user to upgrade. My dilemma is if I've paused the release due to an important fix needed, I don't want to prompt the user to download this version from the AppStore. Is there a way to interpret the *version status* from the payload received from `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.mycompany.myapp`? I get the `version` key-value pair but I don't see a key that suggests the status of that version. I do see `currentVersionReleaseDate`, which I'd think *might* be nil if it's paused or maybe only if it's been removed from for sale? I can't find any documentation that might suggest a solution. Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: I'm afraid what you are trying to doesn't make sense.  It sounds like you want the iTunes Connect server to keep the record of which app version is good and which is bad.  And you want to change it to bad whenever comes up.  If that's what you want to do, you have to do with your own server.

Comment: @ElTomato I was just curious if the currentVersionReleaseDate changed if the app was paused. I already grab the AppStore version from the server, I was just curious if there was any way to interpret the app state from the provided info.